# How to change the color of a #region in Visual Studio's 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, regions

I maybe going mad, but for the life of me I can't find the option to change the colour of collapsed region's in VS2008.

For example if I have the following code:

```cs
#region Test Region

CallSomeCode();

#endregion
```

If I now collapse that region it has the title "Test Region" in a grey text color with a grey box around it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tools→Options→Environment→Fonts and Colors→Display items[Collapsible text]

Comment: Ah, sort of obvious when you say it like that!

Comment: You can't imagine since how much time i'm breaking my eyes with the default color of the collapsible text. It's an happy again developer who thank's you ! hahah

Comment: How has no one given @Jaider credit on his comment.  That's what worked for me too! +1

Answer (score 17):

In VS 2012 the following worked for me:

- To change color of #region / #endregion - set 'Preprocessor Keyword'
- To change the text after #region when collapsed- set 'Collapsed Text (Collapsed)'
- To change the text when expanded - set 'Plain Text', but beware this also changes ; ( [ etc

You may need to restart VS to take effect

*Personally I wish there was two types of comments - one for disabling code, and one for explanatory remarks.  They are two very different things but generally treated the same in most languages*

Comment: For VS2015, to change the text after the `#region`, set "Preprocessor Text" in Fonts and Colors.

Answer (score 15):

For those using VS 2015 that end up here, this is what worked for me in VS 2015:

#region and #endregion Keywords: **Preprocessor Keyword** [immediately applied]

Text After #region Keyword: **Preprocessor Text** [immediately applied]

Collapsed Region: **Collapsed Text (Collapsed)** [must restart Visual Studio]

[image: A Picture]

Comment: Small maybe obvious note, this obviously deals with all preprocessor text like `#if Debug`. I haven't seen any way to target region and more "passive" without affecting conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

in VS 2010, it is Tools→Options→Environment→Fonts and Colors→Code Snippet Field